# Как вывести данные на странице нажатием кнопки?

Tags: python, flask

Я написала генератор случайных фраз на python на основе гугл-таблиц и хочу засунуть его на страницу сайта, так, чтобы фраза (из переменной text) выводилась на странице после нажатия кнопки, а повторным нажатием можно было бы вывести новую фразу, не перезагружая страницу.
Пока все, что у меня есть - код генератора, который можно привести только в сокращенном виде. Я даже не знаю, в какую сторону над этим думать.
Вот кусочек моего кода, если это что-то даст:

```
values_list = []

for value in worksheet.col_values(7):
    values_list.append(value)

text = random.choice(values_list)
```

Comment: Добавьте в ваш сервер flask обработку запроса с конкретным url. С стороны клиента (сайта) отправляйте запрос (ajax) на тот url и получите фразу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Структура проекта**

```
├── generator.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

**generator.py**

```
from flask import Flask
import random
from flask.templating import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

values_list = ['Hello', 'World', 'Python']

# Your code here
# for value in worksheet.col_values(7):
#     values_list.append(value)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/newword')
def new_word():
    return random.choice(values_list)

app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(xhr.response)
                document.getElementById('generator').innerHTML = xhr.responseText
            }
        }
        xhr.open('get', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/newword', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        xhr.send();
    }

</script>
</script>
<body>
    <h4 id="generator">*</h4>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate" onclick="submit()" >
</body>
</html>
```